# Sql server agent job user's password is about to expire

Tags: ssis, sql-server-agent

I have ssis package that is running in sql server agent job. There is a proxy account and it is running through users account but that user has been no longer working with us. The challenge here is his account password is about to expire. so what can be done so that package will be smoothly running after his account password will expire ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the user login you have to map Proxy account to another credential in order to avoid job fails, check [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187890(v=sql.105).aspx). Or you can use local SQL Agent Service account in case all files/folders/sever used by job are accessible for that account.